# Circumventing "Remote Host Identification Has Changed" warning

Tags: linux, ssh, pipe, alias

I'm connecting to a lot of devices that uses the same IP addresses. When I'm plugging them into the router I'm getting the warning message `REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!` and need to run `ssh-keygen -f "/home/xxx/.ssh/known_hosts" -R "xx.xx.xx.xx"` if I still want to connect with the remote host.

My current strategy:

1. I want to create a shortened command from: `ssh-keygen -f "/home/xxx/.ssh/known_hosts" -R "xx.xx.xx.xx"`
2. You can do it from any user.
3. It should be a single command. (So I can copy paste a single line into other terminals in case I have not set it up in `.bash_profile`.
4. The `xx.xx.xx.xx` needs to be configurable.

Since you cannot provide an argument to alias (at least I think so) I tried solving it with `read`:

```
$ alias ssh-keyrm='read LAST_SSH_IP_ADDRESS_CLEARED && ssh-keygen -f "$HOME/.ssh/known_hosts" -R "$LAST_SSH_IP_ADDRESS_CLEARED"'
$ ssh-keyrm
xx.xx.xx.xx
```

Any advice on how I can optimize it further?

Comment: Just as a tangential warning, note that doing this (by any of the means described on this page) means disabling a core part of the SSH security model. It can be OK to do so if, like in your case, you can verify via other means that the host you're connecting to really is the one you expect and trust, but this is _not_ a trick that should be blindly imitated by others just to get rid of annoying error messages. Also, just in case, I would _strongly_ recommend using public key authentication if you do this (or even if you don't, really) to protect against malicious or compromised hosts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Another solution to prevent the host key from being saved in the first place

Please note that this will disable part of what makes ssh secure, the verification that the host you are connecting to is in fact the host you think it is!

Add a section to `~/.ssh/config`

```
host 192.168.*.*
    StrictHostkeyChecking no
    UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
```

Answer (score 16):

If you want to pass arguments to a something pre-defined in Bash, you could use a function instead of an alias to the same effect:

```
ssh-keyrm() { ssh-keygen -f "$HOME/.ssh/known_hosts" -R "$1"; }
```

Which would be run as such:

```
$ ssh-keyrm 127.0.0.1
```

Like aliases, functions can be stored in .bashrc, .bash_profile, or defined inlne in a shell.

Comment: Note: if there is already `ssh-keyrm` alias then `ssh-keyrm()` will trigger it. The OP needs to `unalias ssh-keyrm` first.

Answer (score 13):

> you cannot provide an argument to alias

Bash aliases work as simple expansions (the alias name just gets replaced with the alias value), so they cannot reference *individual* arguments using $n.

However, you can provide arguments as long as they go *at the end* of the command. With an alias like this:

```
alias rmh="ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/known_hosts -R"
```

you can run it as `rmh 192.168.0.1` and although the word `rmh` will be expanded, all arguments following it will still remain in the same place.

Answer (score 8):

I have a similar problem with different devices using the same IP, but took a slightly different approach to solve it: **prevent the host keys from going in to `known_hosts` in the first place**.

```
alias sshn='ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no'
```

Then run `sshn` whenever you want to disable host key security.

```
$ sshn user@192.168.1.1
Warning: Permanently added '192.168.1.1' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.

user@192.168.1.1's password:
```

ssh tells you it added the host to the known hosts, but it didn't actually since the write went to `/dev/null`.  You can suppress this by fiddling with the logging level, but that may turn off other useful messages.

I also have `StrictHostKeyChecking=no` so that it skips the authenticity prompt, but if you'd prefer to see the key fingerprint, you can omit that option.

Comment: In the same direction, I use the following snippet in my `~/.ssh/config`

`host 192.168.2.*
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
    UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null`

Comment: @Pelle: You, sir, are a lifesaver. This is exactly the configuration option I always mean to look up *while* I'm ip-ing a lot of devices, but then always forget once I'm finished, only to be annoyed the next time.

Comment: Ok, I've made an answer from it, tnx for the enthusiasm :)